# How to have a script on my pc be called when my firebase database updates using firebase cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'd like a script on my Windows pc to be called when something is updated in my firebase database. I'm doing the guides for firebase cloud functions (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started). These guides show me how to make scripts that interact with the database. I'm looking for something that would interact with the command line of my computer. Just wondering if it's possible and someone to point me in the right direction.

---

Edit answering comments:

I'm doing this because I have a database on my computer i'd like my ios app to be able to access (I'm really unsure if this is the best way to go about any of this). I want the app to update firebase and then when that update occurs my computer to know this and run a script that grabs info from the database and uploads that to firebase. I'm really a novice at all of this so any better suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: If I may ask, why would you want that ? Why not call an HTTP / HTTPS endpoint on your computer instead ?

Comment: What type of interaction would that script do? The most common use-cases are probably administrative tasks (database maintenance), in which case you'd use the Admin SDK in a Node.js or Java process on your PC: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start